# mysqldump: Error 1412: Table definition has changed, please retry transaction

Tags: mysql

I run a web application on a shared LiteSpeed server with Mariadb version 10.3.22. I do have access to a terminal.

Cron is set up to perform a daily mysqldump, but I now get the error message:

`` mysqldump: Error 1412: Table definition has changed, please retry transaction when dumping table `TABLENAME` at row: 0 ``

I do get a sql file, but it is a little smaller than it used to be. The table that is claimed to have changed it's definition is empty, just as it use to be (as far as I know).
I do not know much about mysql, and I do not understand the message "retry transaction when dumping table `TABLENAME` at row: 0"
Any clues about how to deal with that?

Comment: The structure of the table has changed, compare the table structures from the import and export.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I do that. I do not know much about mysql. I can create a db, add a user and take backup and restore, not much more. I have access to phpMyAdmin.

Comment: In phpadmin you can see the table structure.

Comment: Now I have restored a db dump from before the error message. But there is no difference, the two table structures looks exactly the same.

Comment: extended answer here https://github.com/maxbube/mydumper/issues/8

Comment: Thanks for the link. But it doesn't seem to contain a solution - or I am not able to understand it.

Comment: Are the indexes the same on both tables?

Comment: The page in phpMyAdmin that shows the structure is exactly the same for the table before and after the error occured.

Answer (score 5):

Please check the general log file of mysql service has "TRUNCATE" command on the table or not.

"TRUNCATE" command on the table during the mysqldump process changes table information and changing the command to "DELETE" command solved issue to me.

Default location of general log file is "/var/log/mysql/mysql.log" but it could be changed by "general_log_file" option and "general_log" option on "my.cnf" file.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mysql and getting error of "table defination has changed, please retry transaction " you have to do only one thing that is reconnect to DBMS, it will definitely solve the problem , tere is a button of "reconnect to DBMS" at home Page.